# Microsoft Access single cell in a Multiple Item form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have database including a Multiple Item form. It includes one table and one query which are Budget table and SumofCost query. In budget table, there are `budget codes like 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2 and so on`. What I'm trying to do is that I want a `sum of 1.2.1 and 1.2.2 in 1.2 or 1.1 and 1.2 in 1 cell because they are sub categories`. However, there is not a field in query or table for 1.2 or 1. This means that I have to create a sum for these fields. In multiple items form, 1 and 1.2 cells are empty because I created form according to budget items and if there is not any data for 1 then access makes that field blank. How can I create a sum for these fields? I tried to split this multiple item form and tried to filter according to budget code like `1.* or 1.2.*.` But I couldn't split it. In link there is an example image for what I want to do.

[image]

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a table [Budget]...

```
BudgetCode
----------
1         
1.1       
1.2       
1.2.1     
1.2.2
```

...and a query [SumofCost]...

```
BudgetCode  SumOfCost
----------  ---------
1.1               100
1.2.1             200
1.2.2             150
```

...the query...

```
    SELECT BudgetCode, SumOfCost AS SumOfBudget
    FROM SumofCost
UNION ALL
    SELECT BudgetCode, DSum("SumOfCost", "SumofCost", "BudgetCode LIKE """ & [BudgetCode] & "*""")
    FROM Budget
    WHERE BudgetCode NOT IN (SELECT BudgetCode FROM SumofCost)
ORDER BY 1
```

...produces...

```
BudgetCode  SumOfBudget
----------  -----------
1           450        
1.1         100        
1.2         350        
1.2.1       200        
1.2.2       150
```